# how to do a when X is null then then 'a','b','c'?

Tags: oracle, select, null

How to do

> udfo in ( Case when fund is null then 'a','b','c' else 'd' end )

because you can only do :

> udfo in ( Case when fund is null then 'a' else 'd' end )
>   ?

Comment: Seriously it's not clear... Read your question again.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` and two mutually exclusive conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  ( fund IS NULL     AND udfo IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) )
OR     ( fund IS NOT NULL AND udfo IN ( 'd' ) )
```

You could even implement it using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  CASE WHEN fund IS NULL AND udfo IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )
            THEN 1
            WHEN fund IS NOT NULL AND udfo IN ( 'd' )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END = 1
```

But I find the former version easier to read.